# Resize element height in order to avoid double-scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have designed a page for a customer that incorporates a PDF via an iframe tag. So, if the pdf is large, there are two scrollbars: one of the page and one of the embedded pdf into the iframe (PDF is loaded by the integrated Adobe plugin in the browser). How can I resize dinamically the iframe height in order to maintain the page scrollbar only?

Thanks,
Francesco.

Comment: Add **scrolling="no"** `<iframe src="http://yoursource" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

Comment: @krish: in this mode the PDF can't be viewed per integer but only the first page. In fact the iframe height is not infinite or, however, is not fitted to the pdf original height.

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) to prevent scrollbars

HTML:

```
<iframe src="..." class="pdf-frame"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
.pdf-frame {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have said `<iframe id="myiframe" ...`

You could use jQuery to resize it by setting the height dynamically:

`$("#myiframe").height('someHeight');`

or in javascript:

`document.getElementById("myiframe").style.height = "someHeight";`

or if you are looking for something else there is an interesting article [here (Dynamically resize divs with jQuery)](http://blog.softlayer.com/2012/no-iframes-dynamically-resize-divs-with-jquery/).

Comment: to set the height via jQuery/JavaScript, I need to know what is the PDF height in order to set the correct value. But, since the PDF is loaded dinamically (and it isn't ever the same), I don't know every time the height value of the PDF file, so I don't know what value I can set in $("#myiframe").height('someHeight');